# Host name for nodeJS application on Local Network

Tags: node.js, networking, hosts

I have developed an intranet site using nodeJS and it is running successfully on one of the Windows servers in our office and am now ready to deploy.

At the moment the only route to access is ip:port (192.168.1.88:8888 for example)

I would like for the local users on the network to just type 'intranet' into their browsers and be forwarded to this location. I have tried modifying the system32\drivers\etc\hosts file (with 127.0.0.1 intranet), but it 404'd, telling me that index was not found, so maybe it's trying to serve the application statically with a different web server (IIS is installed on the machine, although it's not running?)

Is there any way to achieve this "shortcut" at network level? It must also work for external visitors to the site so I've ruled out any local solutions.

I am aware that this information already exists online, however I find it is above my knowledge level as a humble javascript developer and seems to strafe into network administration territory. I wonder if anybody could provide a lay mans write up.

Comment: Have you named your server the node app is running on "intranet"? Is your node app running on port 80?

Comment: @DrHund I have now set the node app to port 80 and shortened the url by 5 characters! I have renamed the server to intranet but the browser "Cannot find the server intranet"

Comment: Can you see the server "Intranet" in your network environment?

Comment: @DrHund Indeed I can, It appears in the list of visible machines in my file browser.

Comment: more tests in the shell (Win+R cmd enter): `ping intranet` to see if the server is responding

Comment: next try to download the page using a commandline-tool (e.g. http://curl.haxx.se/download.html): `curl -i intranet`

Comment: if these fail check your firewall / try to connect using the ip instead of the server name